# Настройка ассоциаций файлов с программами

Tags: gnome, ubuntu

Как вручную настроить или подправить ассоциацию типов файлов по расширению с программами для их обработки по умолчанию?

Answer (score 1):

[Официальная справка - изменение ассоциаций файлов с приложениями](http://help.ubuntu.ru/manual/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2#%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)